# Issue exporting object to CSV using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm exporting my object to a csv and I would like to fix up formatting
issues with my object. However I'm able to figure out how to customize my
object values. I would like to leave the id off the csv and format the
amount into currency, any help would be greatly appreciated.  I included a
screen shot of what I would like it to look like on the left and what it
currently looks like on the right.

#### Here is my employee.component.ts

```
export class FetchEmployeeComponent {

   public empList: EmployeeData[];

   exportEsker(data: any) {

       const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value;
       const header = Object.keys(data[0]);

       //Leave off ID col and format Amount as currency????
       const actualheader = ["Employee Name", "Employee No.", "Pur. Type",
"B/P", "Amount"];
       console.log(header);

       console.log(data);
       let csv = data.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify
(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
       csv.unshift(actualheader.join(','));
       let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

       var blob = new Blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' })
       saveAs(blob, "myFile.csv");
   }


   term: string = "";
}

interface EmployeeData {

   id: number;

   name: string;

   empno: string;

   purtype: string;

   bp: string;

   amount: number;
}
```

### console logged data of my object

```
[
 {

    "id": 8,

    "name": "Jeffery W",

    "empno": "80",

    "purtype": "TLS",

    "bp": "B",

    "amount": "20.00"
 },

   {

    "id": 9,

    "name": "Robert P",

    "empno": "101",

    "purtype": "UNI",

    "bp": "B",

    "amount": "9.34"
 },

    {

    "id": 10,

    "name": "Douglas B",

    "empno": "268",

    "purtype": "UNI",

    "bp": "B",

    "amount": "3.94"
 }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is access specific keys from the data which can be done in the naive way of looping through the JSON and selecting specific keys using dot notation ie.. `data.name` etc. and make a new JSON out of these properties and send that JSON across

So your code would change like

```
let csv = newJSON.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify
(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
       csv.unshift(actualheader.join(','));
       let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

       var blob = new Blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' })
       saveAs(blob, "myFile.csv");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you at what point would I be able to access the objects using the dot notation, I'm a little confused. @Vaibhav Kumar Goyal

Comment: @Snowman08 just after  this line `console.log(data);` you have the json in data  object you can access its specific properties using the dot notation